# Background td datatables desde mysql

Tags: mysql, datatables

Busco la forma de cambiar un td en datatables con datos provenientes desde mysql.
Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
createdRow: function ( row, data, index ){ 
    var iduser = data['usuarioid'];
    var color = data['color'];
    if (data['usuarioid'] == iduser ){
        $('td', row).eq(1).css('background-color', '#80ffff');
        }
},
```

Lo cual funciona, pero lo que necesito es que se cargue el color desde la variable color (var color), ya que cada usuario tiene un color definido desde su creacion.
Si pongo el color manualmente funciona, pero cuando quiero llamar a la variable color, simplemente no muestra el color.
Alguna idea de como poder hacerlo?

Saludos y gracias por su ayuda u orientacion.